# $L_1\in P$ , $L_2\in NP$, is it possible that $L_1\cup L_2 \in P$

Tags: complexity-theory, np

Prove\Disprove\Prove that equivalent to $NP=P$ or $NP\ne P$

given $L_1 \in P$ , $L_2 \in NP$ is $L_1 \cup L_2 \in P$?

Obviously $L_1 \cup L_2 \in NP$ because NP is closed under union and $P \subseteq NP$ so $L_1 \in NP$ as well.

I tried to assume in contradiction that $L_1 \cup L_2 \in P$ and build a $TM$ for $L_2$.

Let $M_\cup$ be the $TM$ for $L_1 \cup L_2 \in P$ and let $M_1$ be the $TM$ for $L_1 \in P$

I can accept any $x\in L_2 /(L_1 \cap L_2)$ by checking if $x \in L(M_\cup)$ and checking if $x \notin L(M_1)$

I got stuck trying to determine deterministically whether $x \in L_1 \cap L_2$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless I am mistaken, the answer to your original question "Given $L_1 \in P$, $L_2 \in NP$ is $L_1 \cup L_2 \in P?$" is "not generally, unless $P=NP$" since we can take $L_1 = \emptyset$. Similarly, if we take $L_1 = \Sigma^*$ (the language of all words over the alphabet in question) then $L_1 \cap L_2 = L_2$ so $L_1 \cap L_2 \in P$ cannot hold in general unless $P=NP$.